# How can i restart application gateway in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Current structure of my installation

[image: Current structure of my installation]

I have to restart the application gateway in azure

Comment: Tip: If this is to update its DNS, an alternate route that's less disruptive is to switch the appgw to manual scaling, scale it down to 1 instance, then up to many (the more the better), then back to auto scaling.  This kills off all but 1 instance, then creates a bunch of new instances, then kills off all that aren't needed (most likely including the 1 remaining original), so you get all nodes with refreshed DNS without taking out other sites on the same appgw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway | Stop-AzureRmApplicationGateway | Start-AzureRmApplicationGateway
```

or you can skip the get and just specify what to start\stop. the above will restart all the gateways in the sub. so if this is not something you aim for you should be more specific.

ps. why restart it?

Comment: If you modify the DNS in a vnet that an ILB ASE consumes, you need to restart the appgw. If not, it won't be able to resolve the fqdn of the webapp. That would be a reason to restart it

Answer (score 10):

Or using AZ CLI ( This solved a bouncing backend pool issue )

```
az network application-gateway stop --id /subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<waf-name>

az network application-gateway start --id /subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<waf-name>
```

Answer (score 5):

Open the Azure Cloud Shell or local PowerShell with Az module installed and use the following:

```
# Get Azure Application Gateway
$appgw=Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name <appgw_name> -ResourceGroupName <rg_name>

# Stop the Azure Application Gateway
Stop-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw

# Start the Azure Application Gateway (optional)
Start-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw
```